# VMware workstation Processor Optimization

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

My i5 processor has 4 cores and 4 threads, when running centos 7 VM on VMware workstation 16.2 with the following CPU configuration:-

Number of processors 1
Number of cores per processor: 4

or

Number of processors 2
Number of cores per processor: 2

May I know is there a performance difference? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding VMware, there is no difference between 1-of-4 or 2-of-2.

VMware emulates a CPU by launching one
[thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing))
for each core. In both scenarios, there will be four threads launched.

Some difference may exist for the guest VM, as there would be an impact
on its CPU scheduling algorithm. In the 1-of-4 scenario, the guest OS
might assume that there is less parallelism available, so will use
the virtual CPUs less efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal is half the number of cores, inc HT cores, your computer has.

If your CPU has no HT & 4 real cores, then you need to assign 2 of them, maximum.
1 processor, 2 cores.
This assumes you want maximum speed from both your computer & your VM & that you're only running one VM.

Answer (score 0):

I have VMware V16.2.2 on Windows 10 Pro. It has 2 cores, 4 threads.

Reasonable rule of thumb is half that for VMs and I use 1 CPU with 2 cores for my VMs (all of them).

The machine has a fast SSD and ample memory.

I have 3 Virtual Machines running but I tend to use one at a time or the host (because I tend to work on one thing at one instant in time).

So my Virtual Machines are very fast (I am working in a Kali Machine just now) and my Host Windows 10 is very fast as well.

Using half the total number of cores provides (in my (long) experience with VMware) the best balance for fast Host machine and fast virtual machines.

If you assign too many resources to your VM, your host machine can drag.